# Probability of an outcome happening X number of times on a given number of tries

Tags: probability

I was playing a game and came across a problem which sparked my curiosity.

I had a 25% chance of something happening, and had up to 15 tries to make it happen. I also needed it to happen *twice*. Of course those odds are fairly promising, however it got me thinking, how would I calculate that probability with different variables? What if I had a 10% chance of a favourable outcome, 5 tries, and needed to get it 3 times? Is there some sort of formula for this?

In other words, how would I calculate the possibility of getting an outcome with a probability of P, X times, and out of Y attempts?

Comment: I think an easy approach will be to find the probability of it not happening at all, and the probability of it happening exactly once (for which there are 15 identical ways), all of which can be calculated with binomial. Then, you subtract the sum of all these possibilities from 1.

Comment: Indeed you are looking for binomial distribution with parameter $P$, so if $X$ is the number of times of getting  a determined outcome, $p(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$